# Writing matrices with a variable name coverin some rows and some columns inside the matrix

Tags: matrices

[image: !W C^0 and C^1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBjPy.jpg)

How can I write matrix equations like as shown in the picture? I need augmented matrix with vdots and a variable name inside the matrix which covers multiple rows and columns of the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}
\begin{document}

 \[ \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt} \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.6pt}
T_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
 10& \\[-0.8ex]
 \vdots & C_0 \\
 10
 \end{array}
 \end{bmatrix}
 \;\text{ and }\;
T_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
 10& \\[-0.8ex]
 \vdots & C_1 \\
 10
 \end{array}
 \end{bmatrix}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gave an error with beamer class. But deleting the setlength commands solved it.

Comment: Even `\extrarowheight`?

Comment: yeah. I got '1pt' written as text after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

elementary simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
T_0 = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
        10      &       \\
        \vdots  &   C^0 \\
        10      &
      \end{array}\right]
\quad\text{and}\quad
T_1 = \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
        10      &       \\
        \vdots  &   C^1 \\
        10      &
      \end{array}\right]
\]
\end{document}
```

**addedum:**
or more sophisticated code with use of the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}             % math environments

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]%
{\hskip -0.2\arraycolsep
 \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
 \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
 \array{#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
T_0 =
       \begin{bmatrix}[c @{\ \vline\ } c]
       10       &       \\
       \vdots   &   C^0 \\
       10       &       
      \end{bmatrix}
    \quad\text{and}\quad
T_1 = \begin{bmatrix}[c @{\ \vline\ } c]
       10       &       \\
       \vdots   &   C^1 \\
       10       &       
      \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```